# gaussian filter on irregularly spaced (x,y) series?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

is there an easy way in python to apply a gaussian filter to a set of points (x,y), or more specifically (x,f(x)) that are not regularly spaced along the x-axis?  In response to the request for clarification on what I mean, maybe a better way to describe what I'm looking for is as a "gaussian-weighted average", F<sub>gwa</sub>(X<sub>j</sub>), of a series of points (X<sub>i</sub>,F(X<sub>i</sub>)) where for each point in the provided series (X<sub>i</sub>,F(X<sub>i</sub>)) a sum essentially is taken over all the provided points such that

F<sub>gwa</sub>(X<sub>j</sub>)    =    Σ<sub>i</sub> [ e<sup>-[(X<sub>j</sub>-X<sub>i</sub>)/σ]^2</sup> * F(X<sub>i</sub>) ]    /    Σ<sub>i</sub> [ exp<sup>-[(X<sub>j</sub>-X<sub>i</sub>)/σ]^2</sup> ]

(Note - if the points in (X<sub>i</sub>,F(X<sub>i</sub>)) happen to be evenly spaced, I believe that the end result of the above definition would be the same as what "scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d" does). 
Is there a nice, already-optimized, numpy or scipy way to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "gaussian filter" in this context. Could you give an example of some inputs and the expected output, or at the very least a reference to a description of the operation you're interested in doing?

Comment: added clarification, sorry for the unclarity of the original question.

Comment: If you have a large number of observation, then binning the data and using a equal spaced approach (e.g. savitzky-golay) is much faster than computing the exact local regression for each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [Nadaraya-Watson Kernel Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression#Nadaraya.E2.80.93Watson_kernel_regression), and one available python implementation is in the [statsmodels package](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression.KernelReg.html).

You can do a similar kernel smoothing operation with pandas [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows).

Comment: Thanks.  The Nadaraya-Watson answer + statsmodel package looks the most promising.  As far as I can tell, unless I'm missing something, the pandas rolling window thing you mentioned is just integer index based, and doesn't take any actual irregularity in the provided x-index into account.

Comment: Re: pandas + rolling not being a solution -  try:   >>> ser = pandas.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117]);
>>> print (ser.rolling(window=5, win_type='boxcar',center=True).mean()), you get [NaN,NaN,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.0,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN].  Anyway, the statsmodel package + Nadaraya-Watson suggestion seems promising, will try that.